# Can the arev package provide boldsymbol math?

Tags: fonts, sans-serif, math-fonts

I'm trying out the `arev` package to see how it handles sans-serif mathematics, particularly given that [this document](http://tug.org/pracjourn/2006-1/hartke/hartke.pdf) pegs it as the only available free sans-serif font with a matching mathematics font, other than the bog-standard CM-Bright, and I ran into a warning I can't get rid of,

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMS/zavm/b/n' undefined
(Font)              using `OMS/zavm/m/n' instead on input line 7.
```

which is apparently triggered by using boldsymbol maths such as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{arev}

\begin{document}
$$\boldsymbol\omega$$
\end{document}
```

Is this warning inevitable? If not, then how can one sidestep it? If it is, then why is this, what does it mean, and how bad is it?

Comment: Well, the package says `\SetSymbolFont{symbols}{bold}{OMS}{zavm}{b}{n}`, but `omszavm.fd` doesn't define it (for the simple reason the bold font in OMS encoding does not exist at all).

Answer (score 2):

It means that a bold version of the OMS-encoded font doesn't exist. This won't affect the `\omega` but e.g. `\in` or `\infty`. You can print a glyph table for the OMS-encoding with fonttable:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{arev,fonttable}

\begin{document}
$\omega \in \infty$

\mathversion{bold}
$\omega \in \infty$


\xfonttable{OMS}{zavm}{m}{n}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can avoid the warning by explicitly telling LaTeX to use the non-bold version also with \mathversion{bold}:

```
 \SetSymbolFont{symbols}      {bold}{OMS}{zavm}{m}{n}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it cannot. The package says

```
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}{bold}{OMS}{zavm}{b}{n}
```

but the `omszavm.fd` file only contains

```
\DeclareFontFamily{OMS}{zavm}{}

\DeclareFontShape{OMS}{zavm}{m}{n}{
   <-> zavmr7y
}{}
```

The suffix `y` corresponds to the OMS encoding in Karl Berry’s naming convention; there is no `zavmb7y.tfm` file in the TeX tree. Unless you build one, with the corresponding `.pfb` file, there is no chance of getting bold symbols.

The warning can be silenced by saying

```
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}{bold}{OMS}{zavm}{m}{n}
```

after having loaded the package.